# Return count of records in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have one table like
​

```
​SQL> select * from CRICKET_DETAILS;
TEAM1                TEAM2                WINNER
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
INDIA                PAKISTAN             INDIA
INDIA                SRILANKA             INDIA
SRILANKA             INDIA                INDIA
PAKISTAN             SRILANKA             SRILANKA
PAKISTAN             ENGLAND              PAKISTAN
SRILANKA             ENGLAND              SRILANKA

6 rows selected.
​
```

I want output like this:

```
TEAM          PLAYED      WON      LOST
ENGLAND          2          0         2          
INDIA            3          3         0
PAKISTAN         3          1         2
​SRILANKA         4          2         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `group by` and `union all`:

```
select team, count(*), sum(won), sum(lost)
from ((select team1 as team,
              (case when winner = team1 then 1 else 0 end) as won,
              (case when winner = team1 then 0 else 1 end) as lost
       from cricket_details cd
      ) union all
      (select team2,
              (case when winner = team2 then 1 else 0 end) as won,
              (case when winner = team2 then 0 else 1 end) as lost
       from cricket_details cd
      )
     ) tt
group by team;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff ,this post is very useful for me.Is it any alternative way to achieve the same result.Please let me know.

Comment: @GyanendraKumar . . . There are definitely multiple ways to solve this problem.  None that are simpler come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
select team, count(*) as played, 
       count(case when result = 'W' then 1 end) as won,
       count(case when result = 'L' then 1 end) as lost
from ( select team3 as team, 'W' as result from cricket_details union all
       select case team3 when team1 then team2 else team1 end, 'L' from cricket_details)
group by team;
```